# BIRT table object - Details have too much white space at the bottom

Tags: birt

I've been fighting with this for a few hours now and haven't found a solution.
I'm new to BIRT reports, so it might be something small I'm overlooking here.

I've got a table that shows the correct data and also the correct amount of entries. Between detail and footer there's a huge amount of white space that seems to belong to the details (I coloured the background to check).

I checked the margins an paddings (I didn't set them yet). 
I removed sizes of objects, since I read somewhere that that could cause something similar.
I set the layout to automatic.
I can't find any new articles online to help me out, so I hope someone on here might have had a situation like this or might have an idea.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try correcting the layout and table spacing from the Report Designer ?

Comment: I forgot to add an update. I've been playing around with the layout and the spacing. I removed every entry from the XML to check whether there was any issue there.
I then somehow found out, that table objects add entries for every entry in the DataSet (If I understood it correctly). I used an if statement to filter the unwanted Data out. It worked fine, I only got the wanted data entries. Plus the multiple empty line. I used the filter in the Property Editor and the problem was gone.